# Showing video in its original size

Tags: javascript, youtube, jwplayer

Im pulling video URLs from database(in DB i dont have any other information about video). 
URL can be youtube url or url of video that is hosted somewhere(amazon servers).

Youtube(user has shared you tube video) for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEqyRZks3hw

amazon(user has uploaded video) https://blablabla.s3-external-3.amazonaws.com/video2_1324763440554052-transcoded.mp4

Now i need to play video on the page in its **original** size, in other words viewing video on my page must be the same as viewing on youtube. Same case for uploaded video.

Im using iframe for youtube and jwplayer for uploaded videos.

Comment: @Ethan LongTail, link of what?

Comment: A link to where you are having this issue.

Comment: Well i don't have an issue i'm trying to get solution.

Comment: I don't understand? How could you be looking for a solution if there is no issue?